# Visual Studio Panel mapping

Tags: c#, visual-studio, mapping, panel

I have a program, where I can draw simple shapes on a `panel`, and it tracks my mouse movement.

```
 private void DrawingPanel_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
 {
     toolStripStatusLabel1.Text= e.X + "," + e.Y;
 }
```

I was wondering if there is some way that I can "map" my panel.
By mapping I mean creating areas (with `rectangle coords` f.e.) that will show some message or pop-up information on my cursor when I hover over this area.

Is it possible to do something like that?

EDIT: To be clear - I dont use mouseEvent to draw shape on my panel. I draw them with buttons created on side menu.

EDIT2:
Example: I drew rectangle (10, 10, 20, 20). When i hover my mouse on those coords i would like to get a pop-up at my cursor. Somethinkg like:

```
System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip Rect = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip();
            ToolTip1.SetToolTip(this.Rect, "Reactangle 100 m2");
```

Comment: I'm looking for proper understanding: You are moving & hovering mouse over panel. And You want to see some pop-up (label) moving along with the mouse showing e.g. coords of the mouse, is it right?

Comment: Not exactly, since I can draw shapes on this panel i will track coordinates of those shapes. And later i want to create some pop-up message when i hover my mouse on created shape.

Comment: To answer your question. Yes it is possible. Please narrow the scope of the question.

Comment: I gave an example in EDIT2.

Comment: _I draw them with buttons created on side menu._ Using CreateGraphics?? I hope not, at least not for anything you want to persist. - But: Yes, you can define a set of Rectangle as Viewports and in the Paint event use them to trnalate at clip the Graphics object to them..

Comment: Also, are You using win-forms / GDI+ ? Or is it done through WPF?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to, you can create individual 'viewports' for your drawing panel.

For this your `Paint` event needs to set up the `Graphics` object and can then draw into those 'ports'.

Here is a minimal example..:

[image]

The `Paint` event draws the current ms into three different viewports:

```
private void drawPanel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var v in ViewPorts)
    {
        int i = ViewPorts.IndexOf(v);
        e.Graphics.ResetClip();
        e.Graphics.ResetTransform();

        e.Graphics.SetClip(v);
        e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(v.X, v.Y);
        e.Graphics.Clear(colors[i]);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(DateTime.Now.Millisecond + "' - " +i, 
                              Font, Brushes.Black, 0,0);
    }
}
```

Note how I always can draw to coordinate `(0,0)`!

It uses a few variables:

```
List<Rectangle> ViewPorts = new List<Rectangle>();
List<Color> colors = new List<Color>();
```

Here is how I set up the lists and the animation timer:

```
colors.Add(Color.LightCoral);
colors.Add(Color.LightCyan);
colors.Add(Color.LightGreen);
ViewPorts.Add(new Rectangle(  0,   0, 200, 250));
ViewPorts.Add(new Rectangle(100, 100, 100,  50));
ViewPorts.Add(new Rectangle(210, 200, 100,  50));

Timer t = new Timer();
t.Interval = 250;
t.Tick += (ss, ee) => { drawPanel1.Invalidate(); };
t.Start();
```

You will not use a `Timer` but draw by **changing** viewport specific **data** and calling `Invalidate` on the `Panel` **whenever the data change**..

I have added a `BackColor`, which, just as `ForeColor`, `Fonts` and then some, should better be part of a `ViewPort` class; such a class could also hold a `Draw` method which you would call from the panel's `Paint` event, passing out the `e.Graphics` parameter..

**If** you don't want/need your output to **persist**, which may well be the case for tooltips, you can **skip** the `Paint` event; for this case I would pass out the viewport, have a reference to the target panel in it and use `CreateGraphics` with pretty much the same code as above..

Answer (score 0):

I figured that the easiest way to make a "map" of ma panel is to create areas in `MouseMove event`, and if a mouse move over that area the label with text is created. For example one area has coords of 100,150,200,250 and it looks like this:

```
 public void DrawingPanel2_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) 

    {
            if (e.X >= 100 && e.X <= 150 && e.Y >= 200 && e.Y <= 250)
                {
                    toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Point A";

                    Label lblA = new Label();
                    lblA.Text = "Point A";
                    lblA.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(e.X, e.Y);

                    lblA.AutoSize = true;
                    DrawingPanel2.Controls.Add(lblA);
                }

                else
                {
                    toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = e.X + "," + e.Y;
                    DrawingPanel2.Controls.Clear();
                }
        }
```